# How to string format decimal to keep only one zero

Tags: c#

I like to have a decimal format to 0.9563 so I have things like this:

```
 compData.Comp1Value = String.Format("{0:0,0.####}", Convert.ToDecimal(comp1Val));
```

However, the number comes out like 00.9563. so I added .TrimStart('0') to the end like:

```
 compData.Comp1Value = String.Format("{0:0,0.####}", Convert.ToDecimal(comp1Val)).TrimStart('0');
```

It number came out like .9563.

How do I format it to come out like 0.9563?

Comment: `{0:0,0.####}` Why you need the leading `0,` in format? Just `0.####` should do, no?

Comment: because if the number is 0, then it becomes blank, nothing in it

Answer (score 0):

I change it to {0:0.####} and it works.